# Change data color in a chart

Tags: powerbi, dax

Change data color in a chart
I need to change the columns of a chart depending on the value of the color in RGB stored in another table.

Example, in a table I have the cities with values ​​x, and in another table I have the city code and in another field the value in RGB of the corresponding color.

any property or dax function to do this?

Comment: The Spanish part does not really add anything to the question, it only leads to confusion for non Spanish speakers and is a redundancy for those who do. Please [post in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/375646) or see [StackOverflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I doubt that this is currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible, but was posted as an "Idea" years ago.  Please vote here to add your support:

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/13757925-dynamically-specify-data-colour-using-column-e-g